# Chrome Extension popup button not changing after second press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I've created a chrome extension with a popup that has a button that when clicked fires a js that changes the text of the button. All works as it should but if I click the button a second time, nothing happens and I have to close and re-open the popup to make it work. How could I fix it?

Here's my popup.html:

```
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="toggle.js"></script>
<h3 style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="color: #ff0000;">My Extension</span></strong></h3>
<p style="text-align: center;"><b>Switch</b></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><button id='toggle-btn'>OFF</button></p>
```

And here's toggle.js (that handles the js process):

```
$(function(){

if(!localStorage.getItem('currentState')) {
  localStorage.setItem('currentState', "stop");
}

var $toggleBtn = $("#toggle-btn");
var currentState = localStorage.getItem('currentState');

if(currentState == "stop"){
    $toggleBtn.text("OFF");
} else if (currentState == "start"){
    $toggleBtn.text("ON");
  }

 $toggleBtn.click(function(){
        if(currentState == "start"){
            $toggleBtn.text("OFF");
            localStorage.setItem('currentState', "stop");
            //OTHER ACTIONS
        } else {
            $toggleBtn.text("ON");
            localStorage.setItem('currentState', "start");
            //OTHER ACTIONS
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: do you change the `currentState` when clicking the button? Otherwise it would always have the same state.

Comment: Also check the console to see if any errors show up there. If there are any errors there, they may guide you to what the problem exactly is.

Comment: When I change my text to OFF I switch current stato to stop and when it is on ON I change it to start. There are no errors

Comment: I think you should provide more code, maybe something else is wrong, changing the state should work just fine.

Comment: I've added more code, hope that helps

Comment: You set the localStorage-value but not the `currentState` itself - that's why it works when you reopen the popup, since the `currentState` is then read from the localStorage again

Comment: Hmm I've tryed to re-set the currentState var again after the if statement in the .click function but now the button don't changes text at all

Comment: have you done that with `currentState = "..."` or `var currentState = "..."`?

Comment: Used var currentState... I've now removed the var and replaced it directly with localStorage.getItem('currentState'), working fine!

Comment: the problem was using `var`. you already declared the variable, so re-declaring it inside the function creates a new variable that has nothing to do with the outer variable - using the localStorage to set the value again isn't necessary, but you can do that

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help mate :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not changing the `currentState` value itself in the click-handler but only the `localStorage`. That's why it works when you reopen the popup, as the `currentState` gets assigned to the value of the `localStorage`.

```
localStorage.setItem('currentState', "stop");
currentState = "stop";

localStorage.setItem('currentState', "start");
currentState = "start";
```

should do the trick.